# Librosa: concerning the spectrogram is the sound pressure level a SPL value or a weighted dB(A)?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa, spectrogram

I am new to Python and am trying to analyze an audio with librosa.

Concerning the spectrogram is the sound pressure level a SPL value or a weighted dB(A)?

And does anyone know where I can read about this officially?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a spectrogram has units of dB re full scale or dB re some arbitrary value.

If you want SPL then you need to calibrate your system so that you know what value of SPL full scale equates to.

If you want A weighting then you need to either add a suitable filter in the time domain, or scale the frequency domain amplitudes with the appropriate A weighting values.